# Link array of ImagesViews to TableLayout

Tags: android, imageview, tablelayout

Does anyone know, if you have an array of ImageViews[n][n], how to connect the array to a TableLayout? Furthermore, after it's displayed in the tableLayout, is there a way to tap the images in the table layout and swap places with the adjacent tile with a specific label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will just need to construct your TableLayout manually using `addView()`.

You might want to check out [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) which provides an easy way to "link" data using Adapters.

**Edit** GridView may not work for you because it doesn't specify the number of items per row.

You might also think about making a custom View and rendering your images to a Canvas using the graphics calls in your `onDraw()` method.